# memory caching with catbox and hapi js

Tags: node.js, caching, hapi.js

I am working on memory caching in hapijs with catbox, where a request to DB to get all the rows should be made in these scenarios

- There's a request for a key which isn't in the cached db_result rows then, call DB and update the cache and return the value from cached object
- There's a request for a key which is in the cached db_result rows return the value of the key

For example: If cached `db_result` is `[{ id: 12, name: 'app4' },{ id: 21, name: 'app5' }]` and `key` is `12`, there should be no call to DB, else if key is `13` then a DB call should be made and the `db_result` should get updated.

Is there any example to look at on how to configure this functionality. Am I following the guidelines correct?

please note that we used glue for server configuration on top of hapi.

Answer (score 2):

There is an example [on Github](https://github.com/hapijs/catbox-mongodb/blob/master/examples/hapi.js) of using the Cache-mongodb but the API is consistent with any cache provider.

```
// wildcard route that responds all requests
// either with data from cache or default string
server.route({
  method: 'GET',
  path: '/{path*}',
  handler: async (request, h) => {

      const key = {
          segment: 'examples',
          id: 'myExample'
      };

      // get item from cache segment
      const cached = await Cache.get(key);

      if (cached) {
          return `From cache: ${cached.item}`;
      }

      // fill cache with item
      await Cache.set(key, { item: 'my example' }, 5000);

      return 'my example';
  }
});
```